# Why is props being used over state in this instance?

Tags: react-native

I have two files App.js and Card.js. App.js is taking an array of key,values and rendering it to the screen in the form of Cards. In cards, I take the props from App and assign it to variables in Card's state.

I have a button that calls the function onCardPress() which checks if the Card's state is active and if so then sends an alert displaying what Card I have pressed (cardType).

I notice that the variable returned for cardType is 'undefined' if I use this.state.cardType and the onCardPress function doesn't work since this.state.cardActive is also 'undefined'. However, If I change it to this.props.cardType and this.props.cardActive, I get the correctly passed input from App.js.

Additionally, why doesn't this behavior affect the Image tag in the render function. I can put both this.state and this.props and the image is correctly displayed both time.

Why does this happen?

App.js

```
export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      hand:
      [
      {card: "heart1", key: 1, cardFace: Images.heart1, active: true},
      {card: "heart2", key: 2, cardFace: Images.heart2, active: true},
      {card: "heart6", key: 6, cardFace: Images.heart6, active: true},
      {card: "heart4", key: 4, cardFace: Images.heart4, active: true},
      {card: "heart13", key: 13, cardFace: Images.heart13, active: true}
      ]
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.hand}>
        {
        this.state.hand.map((prop) => {
          return(
            <Card
              cardFace={prop.cardFace}
              key={prop.key}
              cardType={prop.card}
              cardActive={prop.active}
            />
          );
        })
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Card.js

```
export default class Card extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            cardFace: props.cardFace,
            cardType: props.card,
            cardActive: props.active
        };
        this.onCardPress = this.onCardPress.bind(this)
    }

    onCardPress(){
        if(this.state.cardActive==true){
            Alert.alert("pushed " + this.props.cardType)
        }
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <View>
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onCardPress} style={styles.card}>
                <Image source={this.state.cardFace} style={styles.card}/>
            </TouchableOpacity>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake when you try to set your state :

```
this.state = {
    ...
    cardType: props.card,
    ...
};
```

You're trying to get the "card" parameter when you should try to get "cardType".

Correct code should be :

```
this.state = {
    ...
    cardType: props.cardType,
    ...
};
```

Comment: oh my, i've been staring at my code for too long, thanks!